# Google map with too much polygons crashes iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps-api-3, polygons, google-maps-mobile

I have a Google map with 400+ polygons, these polygons consist of 40.000+ lat/lng coordinates. These are all Dutch municipalities, the result can be seen here: http://silktool.com/maptest.php

It works fine (it is a bit slow to load at 2.5MB / 500Kb gzipped) on desktop machines, but when opening the url on an iOS device it crashed Mobile Safari (in Chrome for iOS it works).

I suspect it is because it is just simply too much code or polygons. When I load only half of the polygons, Mobile Safari does not crash.

I load every polygon with the following Javasctipt:

```
var city1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: [
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.0873209365,6.79015076682),
    …many many latlng coordinates… 
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.0716361297,6.81423099069),
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.0873209365,6.79015076682)
  ],
  strokeColor: "#fff",
  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
  strokeWeight: 1,
  fillColor: "rgb(60,255,160)",
  fillOpacity: 0.7
});


var city2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: [
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.0873209365,6.79015076682),
    …many many latlng coordinates… 
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.0716361297,6.81423099069),
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.0873209365,6.79015076682)
  ],
  strokeColor: "#fff",
  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
  strokeWeight: 1,
  fillColor: "rgb(60,255,160)",
  fillOpacity: 0.7
});
```

I want to make the code not crash on iOS and was wondering how to do that?

I've thought of several options, but I don't know if they would work:

- make the code more efficient/compact
- don't use Google maps, but for example Leaflet with a smoothing option to simplify the polygons on different zoom levels (http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#polyline-options)
- put the coordinates in a Javascript array (they are now in a PHP array and the javascript is generated with this).
- more options?

I don't know which option to choose, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should try to render this layer on server side (ex. http://wikimapia.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try to use [google.maps.KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=ru#KmlLayer).

> Have you considered using Google Maps API v3's new KmlLayer? Essentially what happens here is Google acts as a proxy for grabbing any publicly available KML layer, and automatically breaks it up into tiles. This tiled layer can also respond to click events very similar to how a vector layer would. ([link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2147))

Please, refer to [similiar thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/how-do-i-display-geojson-polygons-on-a-map) on https://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks! KML layers seem the way to go. I tested this before but was under the impression that you could not style the KML shapes. However, this is possible (within the KML file).

Comment: Also you can host and edit KML in Google Maps "My places" tool.